# Mongoose accepts null for Number field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema where I'm storing a port number. I also have a default value set for the field.

```
port:{
    type:Number,
    default:1234
}
```

If I don't get any value via my API, it gets set to `1234`.
However, If someone sends `null`, it accepts `null` and saves to database.

Shouldn't it covert `null` to `1234`? `null` is not a number! Am I understanding it wrong?

I am considering the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38256874/4308032), but I dont want to add extra code for something that should work without it (unless I'm wrong and its not supposed to convert `null` to `1234`)

Comment: It's more of a [JavaScript artifact](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) that the basics of the "types" in mongoose are based on. So it depends if you can either live with simply throwing an exception ( which you can do with a simple validator ) or supplanting `null` with a "default" value where it is supplied, which is done in "pre" hooks as you mention. Or instead make sure the inputs are `undefined` instead of `null`, and then the "default" just works as expected.

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208127/mongoose-accepts-null-for-number-field/45211501#45211501) below help you? Any comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the comments in this issue:

- https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2438

> null is a valid value for a Date property, unless you specify required. Defaults only get set if the value is undefined, not if its falsy.

(it's about dates but it can be applied to numbers just as well.)

Your options are to either:

- add `required` to the field
- add a custom validator that would reject it
- use hooks/middleware to fix the issue

You might get away with a pre-save or post-validate (or some other) hook like this:

```
YourCollection.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.port === null) {
    this.port = undefined;
  }
  next();
});
```

but probably you'll have to use something like:

```
YourCollection.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.port === null) {
    this.port = 1234; // get it from the schema object instead of hardcoding
  }
  next();
});
```

See also this answer for some tricks on how to make `null` trigger default values in function invocation:

- [Passing in NULL as a parameter in ES6 does not use the default parameter when one is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725034/passing-in-null-as-a-parameter-in-es6-does-not-use-the-default-parameter-when-on/43519507#43519507)

This is unfortunate that Mongoose cannot be configured to tread `null` as `undefined` (with some "not-null" parameter or something like that) because it is sometimes the case that you work with data that you got in a request as JSON and it can sometimes convert `undefined` to null:

```
> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([ undefined ]));
[ null ]
```

or even add `null` values where there was no (explicit) `undefined`:

```
> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([ 1,,2 ]));
[ 1, null, 2 ]
```

Comment: Good answer.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in mongoose official docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Number
To declare a path as a number, you may use either the Number global constructor or the string 'Number'.

```
const schema1 = new Schema({ age: Number }); // age will be cast to a Number
const schema2 = new Schema({ age: 'Number' }); // Equivalent
```

```
const Car = mongoose.model('Car', schema2);
There are several types of values that will be successfully cast to a Number.
```

```
new Car({ age: '15' }).age; // 15 as a Number
new Car({ age: true }).age; // 1 as a Number
new Car({ age: false }).age; // 0 as a Number
new Car({ age: { valueOf: () => 83 } }).age; // 83 as a Number
```

If you pass an object with a valueOf() function that returns a Number, Mongoose will call it and assign the returned value to the path.

The values null and undefined are not cast.

NaN, strings that cast to NaN, arrays, and objects that don't have a valueOf() function will all result in a CastError.